# Bind one-many relation model in the view in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, one-to-many

I have a user registration page where i uses a tabbed layout.In the first tab i will enter the personal details and in the second tab I want to enter a couple of references provied by the user.

I have created a viewmodel and binded the viewmodel to the View.The problem is i cannot access properties in the `Relation class` in the View

I am using two simple models

```
 public partial class WalkInn
{
    public WalkInn()
    {
        this.tblWalkIn_Relation = new HashSet<WalkIn_Relation>();

    }

    public long WALKINID { get; set; }
    public long LOGINID { get; set; }
    public string CANDIDATE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string FATHER_SPOUSE_NAME { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public virtual Login tblLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WalkIn_Relation> tblWalkIn_Relation { get; set; }

}

public partial class WalkIn_Relation
{
    public long RELATIONID { get; set; }
    public long WALKINID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string RELATION { get; set; }       

    public virtual WalkInn tblWalkInn { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel is as follows

```
public class WalkInnVM
{
    public WalkInn WalkInn { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WalkIn_Relation> WalkInRelation { get; set; }
}
```

View is as follows

```
@model CRM.Models.ViewModels.WalkInnVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add2";
 }

 <h2>Add WalkInn</h2>

 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.WalkInn.CANDIDATE_NAME)

  **Cannot access the below code**
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.WalkInn_Relation.Name)
```

Comment: `WalkInRelation` is a collection. You need a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` to access each property of `WalkIn_Relation`

Comment: How can i achieve the above?Can you provide an example.

Comment: It depends on what you actually want to do. Are you generating a fixed number of items in the collection, or do you want to be able to dynamically add any number of new items?

Comment: I want only 2 references to be entered by the user.

Comment: Add 2 instances to you collection in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. Change the property to be `IList<WalkIn_Relation>` and then use `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.WalkInRelation.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WalkInRelation[i].Name }`